# How to use combobox to search for record?

Tags: ms-access, combobox, vba

I have a combo box on a form that I use to search for record based on `[WorkDate]` and it works fine. the problem i have is that the combo box has 3 columns but it only does the lookup based on the first column. The columns in the combobox dropdown are `WorkDate | WorkType | Comment`

here is the code i have:

```
`Private Sub ctlSearch_AfterUpdate()
    On Error GoTo myError
    Dim rst As DAO.Recordset
    Set rst = Me.RecordsetClone
    rst.FindFirst "[WorkDate] = " & "#" & Format(Me.ctlSearch.Column(0), "yyyy/mm/dd") & "#" And "[WorkType] = '" & Me.ctlSearch.Column(1) & "'"
    Me.Bookmark = rst.Bookmark
leave:
    Me!ctlSearch = Null
    If Not rst Is Nothing Then Set rst = Nothing
    Exit Sub
myError:
    MsgBox "Record Not Found"
    Resume leave
End Sub`
```

I have narrowed down the issue to this line in the code:

```
rst.FindFirst "[WorkDate] = " & "#" & Format(Me.ctlSearch.Column(0), "yyyy/mm/dd") & "#" And "[WorkType] = '" & Me.ctlSearch.Column(1) & "'"
```

Also whenever I replace the above line of code with

```
rst.FindFirst "[WorkDate] = " & "#" & Format(Me.ctlSearch.Column(0), "yyyy/mm/dd") & "#"
```

or

```
rst.FindFirst "[WorkType] = '" & Me.ctlSearch.Column(1) & "'"
```

it works perfectly but for the life of me I cant get the lookup to work together. I have spent days trying to get this to work. Any help will be much appreciate.

Comment: To assist in solving the problem, the first step should be to make sure your search string is correct. See this example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18019125/how-to-use-multiple-criteria-with-find-in-vba  The short version is Debug.Print "[WorkDate] = " & "#" & Format(Me.ctlSearch.Column(0), "yyyy/mm/dd") & "#" And "[WorkType] = '" & Me.ctlSearch.Column(1) & "'"     What does your search string look like?

Answer (score 2):

You have a typo in your line.  When you tried to combine the statements it looks like you added some extra quotes around the `AND` part.

```
rst.FindFirst "[WorkDate] = " & "#" & Format(Me.ctlSearch.Column(0), "yyyy/mm/dd") & "#" And "[WorkType] = '" & Me.ctlSearch.Column(1) & "'"

rst.FindFirst "[WorkDate] = #" & Format(Me.ctlSearch.Column(0), "yyyy/mm/dd") & "# And [WorkType] = '" & Me.ctlSearch.Column(1) & "'"
```

When writing a query statement in VBA the needs to be a string contained in quotes like so.

`rst.FindFirst "Field1 = #01/02/2014#"`

If you want to change the date to be a variable of some sort you need to append it to the string like you did above.

`rst.FindFirst "Field1 = #" & dateField & "#"`

The difference between what I wrote and what you had is that you don't need to divide the string up and put quotes around every part.  Quotes only need to surround the parts that aren't variables.

Comment: Thanks for this it worked perfectly. I wish I understood how the quotes work. I you have a reference on clarifying how to use quotes in these situation I'd love to have a look at it. thanks again.

Comment: @Kefash I edited my answer.  Hopefully it is a little more helpful.

Comment: That was helpful. I couldn't any explanation anywhere. or maybe I wasn't searching properly. :)